# Error with SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, audio-player, android-music-player

```
06-19 12:36:06.181: E/Inside log(15543): /sdcard/songs/(04) Fall Out Boy - Sugar, We're Goin' Down [2005].mp3
06-19 12:36:06.286: E/IMediaMetadataRetriever(15543): extractMetadata error
06-19 12:36:06.391: E/SQLiteLog(15543): (1) near "re": syntax error
06-19 12:36:06.421: E/AndroidRuntime(15543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 12:36:06.421: E/AndroidRuntime(15543): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "re": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into SongDataBase(name,artist,genre,composer,albumname,year,path) values('Sugar, We're Goin' Down','Fall Out Boy','Punk','null','From Under The Cork Tree','2005','/sdcard/songs/(04) Fall Out Boy - Sugar, We're Goin' Down [2005].mp3')
```

Code:

```
if(name!=null)
{
    if(name.contains("'"))
    {
        name.replaceAll("'", "\'");
    }
}
if(genre!=null)
{
    if(genre.contains("'"))
    {
        genre.replaceAll("'", "\'");
    }
}
if(composer!=null)
{
    if(composer.contains("'"))
    {
        composer.replaceAll("'", "\'");
    }
}
if(albumname!=null)
{
    SQLiteDatabase database=getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("insert into SongDataBase(name,artist,genre,composer,albumname,year,path) values('"+name+"','"+artist+"','"+genre+"','"+composer+"','"+albumname+"','"+yea‌​r+"','"+pathfile+"')");
}
```

Comment: you should write your insert query code as well. because its unformatted.

Comment: It seems obvious that the `'`in the song title is a problem for the query, but it's not really clear what your problem actually is.

Comment: seems to be a problem here "   'Sugar, We're Goin' Down',   "

Comment: I am trying to insert data into the database using mediametadataretriever the problem is with some query. The single quotes are causing a problem. I dunno how do i rectify this.

Comment: So what does your query code look like?

Comment: if(name!=null)
  {
  if(name.contains("'"))
  {
  name.replaceAll("'", "\'");
  }
  }
  if(genre!=null)
  {
  if(genre.contains("'"))
  {
  genre.replaceAll("'", "\'");
  }
  }
  if(composer!=null)
  {
  if(composer.contains("'"))
  {
  composer.replaceAll("'", "\'");
  }
  }
  if(albumname!=null)
  {
 
  
  SQLiteDatabase database=getWritableDatabase();
  database.execSQL("insert into SongDataBase(name,artist,genre,composer,albumname,year,path) values('"+name+"','"+artist+"','"+genre+"','"+composer+"','"+albumname+"','"+year+"','"+pathfile+"')");

Comment: there are similar if condtions for albumname and pathfile

Comment: a ***VERY URGENT*** playlist...  and yet you post no supporting code?

Answer (score 6):

You need to **double** (**''**) the apostrophes (**'**) in your strings.
Otherwise, they will be treated as `string delimiters`, breaking your string values.

A better solution, though, would be to pass **bound** parameters (using the **?** placeholders, which will be then filled by the values stored in a string array you would pass).
This way, the string conversion is handles **automatically**, and you don't have to double the quotes.

---

OK, by analyzing your code, the problem pops out very clearly:
You **don't perform** the quote replacement on the `Artist`, the `Album Name` and on the `File Path`.
You only do that on Name, Genre and Composer.

In your case, the **path** is giving you the error.

It's clear from this error message:

```
/sdcard/songs/(04) Fall Out Boy - Sugar, We're Goin' Down [2005].mp3
```

Comment: No, backslashes do not work in SQLite, or any other SQL database; this is not MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a question you should provide more info (sample code, etc.). However you problem is quite clear, you only have to see the log file:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "re": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into SongDataBase(name,artist,genre,composer,albumname,year,path) values('Sugar, We're Goin' Down','Fall Out Boy','Pu
```

You need to escape the character `'` in the piece of code you use to create that query. If you don't provide sample code I can't be more specific. But it's quite simple to resolve.